# Recuperar valor angularjs POST

Tags: angularjs, http, post

Como recupero o valor no arquivo php quando uso esse método de post do angularjs?

```
 $http({
                    method  : 'POST',
                    url     : 'xxxxxxx.com/consulta.php',
                    data    : JSON.stringify($scope.newName),
                    headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' } 
                    }) .success(function (data) {
                $scope.nomes = data;            
            });
```

Eu envio os parâmetros pelo data    : JSON.stringify($scope.newName)

No arquivo php como recupero esse valor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A passagem do parametro data tem de ser feito como um par de atributos como o exemplo que segue:

```
...
data : {c: JSON.stringify(nomeObj)},
...
```

Na parte PHP:

```
$data = file_get_contents("php://input");
$data = json_decode($data);
$c = json_decode($data->c); //o ->c tem de ter a mesma designação que é passado
```

Espero que ajude.

Comment: Funcionou, obrigado, e como faço para passar 2 parâmetros?

Comment: @YuriRodrigues Passa um array com os 2 parâmetros :)